# Web API design issue - preventing users from using PUT/PATCH to update user id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am running into a bit of a design issue with how to prevent users from updating the user id field in the data being posted to the API. I am using ASP.Net Core 2.1 and Entity Framework Core. This API will be used with a web app (I will be building that too) and both applications will require authentication along with policy authorization.

I have an event class that references who the user was that created it (User id + navigation property of user to my user entity). Anytime the API is called using PUT/PATCH/DELETE, I want to prevent users from being able to update the user id field and deleting other users events.

The API can be called with all the HTTP verbs for example a GET request to `api/events` to list all events or a POST to `api/events` to create an event.

**My event entity:**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }   
public string Url { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }
public Guid UserId { get; set; }
public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

**Event update data model (for PUT/PATCH requests):**

```
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
public DateTime? ScheduledTime { get; set; }
```

**My user entity**

```
public Guid Id { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public List<Event> Events { get; set; } = new List<Event>();
```

The route for my controller is very simple:  `[Route("api/[controller]")]` so its accessed by `api/events`.

Currently the approach I have taken is to explicitly pass in the user id to the API. In the action, I fetch the event from the database, compare the values of the user id that was passed in to the user id fetched from the database. If its the same, I allow the update to happen. If its different, I return a 403 forbidden along with an error message.

**I.e. My update action in the API:**

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEvent([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromQuery] Guid userId,[FromBody] EventUpdateDto eventToUpdate)
{
//compare userId passed to action by fetching event from database and compare values
//return 403 if not equal else continue
}
```

The problem is that I am using both route parameters and query string parameters. I can simplify the route to be `{eventid}/{userid}` but I don't know if this is best practice. This would mean that I am calling my API to update a specific event but then also drilling into a specific User which does not make much sense. I also didn't want to go the other way of `api/{userid}/events/{eventid}` for my controller because I want to access all events for all users or a single event in my web application - I don't want it to be limited to only pull events for a single userid.

I also have the same issue with DELETE as I don't want a user deleting other users posts. So its setup as below:

```
[HttpDelete("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEvent([FromRoute] Guid id, [FromQuery] Guid userId)
```

Note that my update model does not contain UserId just because I wanted to prevent it from being overridden. I came up with 3 separate approaches to this issue and am wondering which one is the correct path to take and if there is a better design for this.

**1)** Remove any check for userid validation from the API and place logic into the web application that will be calling the API. With this approach, every time a user tries to edit an event in the application, I'll first have to fetch the event from the API, compare the current userid to the userid fetched from API and either let them continue or throw error. My only issue with this was that an extra trip to the API has to take place instead of one (fetch event first then possibly post event). With this approach, my event update model can safely have userid field in it and I can simplify my API call without a query string parameter.

**2)** Modify my approach above slightly to not use query string parameters and only use route parameters. Instead of calling `api/events/1?id=1`, modify it to look like `api/events/1/1` where the first parameter is the eventId, and the second the userId. I feel that creating these type of URLs will be easier in the application but stray from proper REST practices.

**3)** Keep my current approach.

I am a bit hesitant on approach #1 due to possible performance issues along with wanting to have an API that is self-contained so that it can be plugged into other applications without having to write complex logic in the web app. Is one approach better than the other? Is there a better approach I can take with designing my outer facing models? Any help on the design would be very helpful.

Comment: Why do you accept the user id in the update event? What's to stop a malicious user providing another user's id?

Comment: Do you have an authentication of some kind? If so, then current user is in `this.User` property of your controller.

Comment: @John That's why I'm not sure how to approach this. In my web app, I will be storing the user ID in session storage on the server. Whenever the API is called, all calls that require a user id to be sent will be sent using this value. The API is also secured with a JWT token. In the end I'm confused as to what the correct process is to prevent exactly the thing you mentioned.

Comment: @vasily.sib Authentication is in the from of a JWT. I am using Auth0 to get an access token for my API. Users will primarily be using social logins. I don't see any user specific claims (that have to do with name/email) in my access token although I could add some custom claims to the access token if needed.

Comment: Then you can add custom claim with your user id. Now you don't need to pass `userId` in your request path as it stored in JWT. Also, this is more RESTful way as now your resource URI is depend only on resource it self.

Comment: @vasily.sib I'm not quite sure how to modify the access token. I am relying on Auth0 to provide the access token. I can add rules on their end to enrich my access token (like userID) but the userID provided by social providers seems to not be a guid. Not sure if you can add custom claims after you already have an access token in the application.

Comment: You can add rules on their end to enrich your access tokens with `userID` provided by social providers. Then you can store a relation "social provider `userId` -> your `user` object in db".

Comment: "I will be storing the user ID in session storage on the server" please don't store anything in in memory sessions, this is a bad idea.

Comment: @matt_lethargic Would it be better as vasily_sib pointed out to store the userid in the JWT and access it that way instead? Or can I use some other place to store session data. Something like a redis cache?

Comment: JWT all the way. Quite often you'll have a 'subject id' or SID in a jwt, this is the user id, get the user id from the token. Even if you still pass in the user id in your url/route you can cross reference the user id in the request to the one in the token, obvs the token is the correct one. If they don't match return 401. Redis is a great alternative to in-memory sessions, but not for this.

Comment: @matt_lethargic Thanks Matt. I'll go down that route of getting the sub claim (I tested this and it works as expected) from the JWT and using that to verify ownership of data points. I'll also combine this with policies and roles to verify a user can't do stuff they are not allowed to. Lot to do and a lot to learn but excited. Thanks for your input. For redis, I won't it using it for the API but might end up implementing it for the web application for storing user search history.